# Can "sitting down" be both an act and a state?

Tags: idioms, american-english

This is in reference to American English (I'm in the US).

Obviously the following is common usage: "I sat down.", indicating an act.

But is the following also correct:

> I don't like to stand up after a period of sitting down.

That would indicate a state. Are both of these normal? I added "down" because omitting it and saying "I don't like to stand up after a period of sitting" doesn't sound complete to me, for some reason, but I guess I could have done that as well.

Comment: Yes, gerunds are sometimes used for both an act and the state resulting from that act. If you don't care for it, you can use "being seated" to refer to the state.

Comment: *Standing up* is the same - *standing up makes me dizzy* could refer either to the act of rising, or being on your feet a long time (although there are many other phrases for being on your feet, so you might more commonly use *standing up* to mean rising).

Comment: "Standing up" and "sitting down" are actions, whereas "standing" and "sitting" are states.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of, the answer that they can't be the same (which I thought they could be), coming from a poster with an 18k reputation ("Weather Vane") which contradicts my own and apparently some other people's understanding here.

Comment: Not really: StuartF remarked that "standing up" commonly means "rising".

Comment: Particularly with states that refer to human body positions, which are enshrined in English (and no doubt other languages') verbal meanings. The human body that's not in motion is generally in one of three positions: lying, standing, sitting. The verbs associated with them can refer to the position ("stative" verbs) or to the beginning of the state ("inchoative verbs"). E.g, _They stood in the sun for four hours_ versus _They stood immediately when she entered._ Since these are human postures that have human actors, these inchoative verbs are active, not stative.

Comment: I understand that. The question is, **can** "sitting down" or "standing up" also signify a state, even if it's not primarily used for that purpose. The last two replies suggest that they **can't** while the first two suggest that they can.

Comment: Hello, 783. Different verb-forms can have different distributions: 'sit down' and 'sitting down' don't match exactly (eg 'He did the ironing sitting down').

Comment: Pretty much **any** verb that refers to position or movement can be used to refer to an act or a state, though details of doing so will vary, like most derivational morphology.

Comment: @WeatherVane: A stand up comedian does not rise from being seated or prone. "Standing up for hours on end can be painful" is generally considered to be correct when referring to the act of standing. Yes, you could remove "up" and retain the meaning, but even with the "up" it is considered to refer to the state of standing upright as opposed to the act of rising.

Comment: @WeatherVane I strongly disagree. “Sitting down” and “sitting” are virtually interchangeable, as either states or actions, at least in General American English.

Comment: Always fun when a phrase has two (or more) meanings:  I'm not sitting down because I'm sitting down.   I'm not [yet/currently] sitting down because I'm [in the process of] sitting down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Sitting down *can* be both an act and a state

It can very easily refer to the state. For example, any English speaker will consider this remark perfectly normal, and will all agree on its meaning:

> I am sorry to be phoning you unannounced. Before I tell you what has happened, may I ask if you are sitting down?

#### In your case, the `down` is to give balance

It is not *needed* grammatically, but it is certainly beneficial to give  the sentence

- a verb and a preposition in each half, and
- a similar spoken rhythm in each half.

Like you, I think it sounds better with the `down` than without it.

Comment: Yes. Another example is when Alice tells Bob to sit down and Bob says, "But I *am* sitting down!"

Comment: @MarcInManhattan And in parallel, if she just tells him to sit (like one might say to a dog), he'll just respond "But I *am* sitting."

Comment: It can also be a, um, noun (?).  Ooof!  I enjoy having a good sit-down!  Grommit, time for a sit-down!

Comment: Prof, I think your "usually" is confusing.  It may make the ESL speaker think that it's unusual, strange, or sounds wrong.  Sentences like "I'm sitting down for this" or "I'm already sitting down" are commonplace.

Comment: Yes, you can also "sit up", which is pretty much the same physical position as "sitting down", only it implies that you A.) are paying attention now as well, or B.) were previously slouching or lying down.

Comment: Agreed, I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context *and* the commonly accepted meaning associated with that context, *or*, to whom you are sharing your thoughts.

You can rephrase your example as:

> I don't like to stand up after sitting down for a period.

or

> I don't like to stand up after sitting down for a period of time.

In this case, 'sitting down' would tend to be accepted as a state rather than an act, because of the duration indication (it would have been different if the 'down' had been omitted, then sitting could again refer to meditation or posing).

If you write:

> I don't like to stand up right after sitting down.

Then an *act* is implied, indicated by the short duration of the motion ('right after').

Note that if you omit the 'down' from your example:

> I don't like to stand up after a period of sitting.

In the context of yoga or meditation practice, this indicates the act of having a sitting (meditating in a sitting position) and implies a state (that of meditating).
If you are a model and pose for painters or photographers, sitting as used above would also both be a state (the seated position) and an act (that of posing).

Answer (score -2):

No. *Sitting down* implies an act in-process by merit of a given direction (down); *sitting* is a state that requires no qualifier, such as direction or orientation (omit *down*).

Comment: This is 100% incorrect.

Comment: While reading this, I'm currently  *sitting down* and have been for some time.  Just as well I was already *sitting down* otherwise I would have fallen over in shock.